# How to select specific columns from Spark DataFrame based on the value of another column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider a DataFrame `df` with 4 columns `c0`, `c1`, `c2` and `c3` where `c0` and `c1` are nested columns(struct type) and the other two are string type:

```
root
 |-- c0: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- y: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- y: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c3: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to select all the values of `c0` or `c1` based on the value of `c3`.

***Example:*** If the value of `c3` is "d", I want to select `c0.*` else `c1.*`

This is what I've tried so far but without luck:

**Approach:** Using when and otherwise inside the select clause.

```
.select(
  col("c3"),
  col("c4"),
  when(col("c3") === "d", col("c0.*").otherwise(col("c1.*"))))
```

This gives the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Invalid usage of '*' in expression 'casewhen';
```

Then instead of using `col` I've tried using `df`:

```
.select(
  col("c3"),
  col("c4"),
  when(col("c3") =!= "d", df("c0").otherwise(df("c1"))))
```

This gives the following exception:

```
otherwise() can only be applied on a Column previously generated by when()
```

Any help on this would be appreciated!

PS: I'm a beginner in Spark :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first get the struct you want using when and then use `*` to select the nested fields like this:

```
df.withColumn("c01", when($"c3" === "d", $"c0").otherwise($"c1"))
  .select($"c2", $"c3", $"c01.*")
```

For the other error:

> otherwise() can only be applied on a Column previously generated by when()

You're simply missing a bracket as you call otherwise on `df("c0")` instead of the `when` column.